# i have a json data and i only return a captains on that data dynamically

Tags: objective-c

```
{
"team":
{
"players":
 {
  "1":
   {
    "teamName":"Royal Challenge Bangalore",
    "shortName":"RCB",
    "11":{
    "name":"Virat Kholi",
    "Iscaptain":true,
    "postion":"2",
    "runs":"6000"
       },
    "12":{
    "name":"Chris Gyale",
    "postion":"1",
    "runs":"4000"
       },
    "13":{
    "name":"AB",
    "postion":"4",
    "runs":"5000"
       }
   },
   "2":
   {
    "teamName":"Kolkatta Knight Riders",
    "shortName":"KKR",
    "11":{
    "name":"Robin Uttapa",
    "postion":"1",
    "runs":"6000"
       },
    "12":{
    "name":"Sunil Narayan",
    "postion":"2",
    "runs":"4000"
       },
    "13":{
    "name":"Gautam Ganmbhir",
    "Iscaptain":true,
    "postion":"4",
    "runs":"5000"

       }    
     }
  }
 }
}`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way. `captains` will contain `NSDictionary` objects with related data

```
    NSString *json = @"your json here...";
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[json dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                         options:0
                                                           error:&error];

    if (error) {
        // TODO: handle error...
    }

    NSArray *teams = [[[dict objectForKey:@"team"] objectForKey:@"players"] allObjects];
    NSMutableArray *captains = [NSMutableArray new];

    for (NSDictionary *team in teams) {
        for (id item in [team allValues]) {
            if ([item isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
                if ([(NSDictionary *) item objectForKey:@"Iscaptain"]) {
                    [captains addObject:item];
                }
            }
        }
    }
```